# Hebrew in comments and sidebars is too small to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hebrew, font

The current font used on site (Georgia) renders Hebrew letters smaller than their English counterparts. In posts, this causes no problems, as 15px is plenty large enough to read clearly. However in comments and in sidebars (13 and 12 px, respectively) it becomes hard to discern nekudos (vowels) and even between certain similar letters (ר - ד , כ - ב).

Is changing just the font size of the Hebrew letters while leaving the English the same possible/practical? If not, is there a similar font that has slightly larger Hebrew letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have increased the font size in the Linked and Related section. The change will be in the next production build.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks; but note that the question also was about comments. Ping @HodofHod.

Comment: @msh210 I have increased comment font size as well.

Comment: @msh210 True!! I completely missed that. Something's not functioning upstairs today. Jin, thank you!

Comment: Yes, thank you, Jin!